# create query with parameter that can be null

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I create this method:

```
public List SearchUsers(Users user)
{
    List lstUser;
    using (var ctx = new MyEntities())
    {
        result = ctx.User
            .Where(u=>u.Name.Contains(user.Name) && u=>u.ID==user.ID)
            .OrderByDescending(u => u.ID)
            .ToList();
        return lstUser;
    }
}
```

When I call it, should `user.name`, `user.ID` parameters have value, but I want to be null sometimes. `ID` is `int` , `name` is `string(30)`. I read them from textbox.

How to create and call this method?

Comment: I have no idea what your asking but your code is using undefined variables (result), your lambda has two lambdas, unbalanced parentheses, etc. in short not much about this code is correct.

Comment: i update code.please review and help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this might do the trick:
Either fill userName and userId when calling the method, or leave one or both null as suits to disable that part of the search.

```
public List<User> SearchUsers(string userName, int? userId)
{
    using (var ctx = new MyEntities())
    {
        IQueryable<User> query = ctx.User;

        if (userName != null)
            query = query.Where(u=>u.Name.Contains(userName));

        if (userId != null)
            query = query.Where(u=>u.ID==userId.Value);

        var users = query
            .OrderByDescending(u => u.ID)
            .ToList();

        return users;
    }
}
```

Comment: error occur in this line:             query = query.Where(u=>u.Name.Contains(userName));

Comment: error occur in this line:    query = query.Where(u=>u.Name.Contains(userName));and error is:can not implicity convert IQueryable DAL.User to DbSet DAL.User